# cache.writeQuery is just, not adding to cache

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm using `cache.writeQuery` to update my cache after a mutation, and it just is not updating the cache. The updates just aren't in there.

This is in my `update()` callback from the `useMutation`:

```
 const userData = copy(cache.readQuery({
     query: GET_USER
 }))

 userData.me.categories.push(newCategory)

 cache.writeQuery({
    query: GET_USER,
    data: userData
 })

 console.log('New category shows up here:')
 console.log(userData.me.categories.map(category => category.id))

 const _userData = copy(cache.readQuery({
    query: GET_USER,
 }))

 console.log('New category is not in here:')
 console.log(_userData.me.categories.map(category => category.id))
```

I'm deep-cloning my user data, and simply pushing onto its categories. It just doesn't want to store the updated data. It's clearly doing *something*, insofar as I can mutate all my existing categories and change their names etc, it just will not add a new one.

What can I try next?